# "Helmet is not a function", when trying to use it with Express

Tags: node.js, express, electron, helmet.js

i have an Electron Project where I installed Helmet, and I'm trying to use it with express, but I get the error "Helmet is not a function", during build. Also, in VScode my instantiated Helmet is with color blue, and not yellow as other instantiated variables.

Other dependencies, like Morgan and Cors did not triggered this error:

[image]

```
const express = require('express')
const cors = require('cors')
const helmet = require('helmet')
const morgan = require('morgan')
 
const app = express();
 
app.use(cors({ origin: process.env.CORS_ORIGIN || '*' }));
 
//error here
app.use(helmet());
 
app.use(express.json());
 
app.use(morgan('dev'));
```

Dependencies in my package.json:

```
 "dependencies": {
    "@mdi/font": "5.9.55",
    "core-js": "^3.8.3",
    "cors": "^2.8.5",
    "dotenv": "^16.0.3",
    "express": "^4.18.2",
    "helmet": "^6.0.0",
    "morgan": "^1.10.0",
    "roboto-fontface": "*",
    "socket.io": "^4.5.3",
    "vue": "^3.2.13",
    "vuetify": "^3.0.0-beta.0",
    "webfontloader": "^1.0.0",
    "ws": "^8.11.0"
  },
```

Comment: You can check what is it, use debugger or `console.log(helmet)`

Answer (score 0):

This is a very common issue and is normally due to the actual installation or version.

The best thing to do is go to your shell and type `npm helmet uninstall` to uninstall whatever version of helmet there is. This might take some time.

Next, go back to the shell and enter the folder with all the files using `cd [name of folder]`. Then, once you are in the folder with all the files, type `npm i helmet` to install it in the correct place with the right version. Hope this helps.

Another way is to find where helm.exe was installed on your computer. Open it. You may get a message about how it's not safe. Run it and follow the instructions that follow.